# Obtain and minus total number of observation from multiple datasets in SAS

Tags: sas, sum, proc-sql

I have to prepare 5 tables from a large dataset given certain conditions.
The total number of obs for 5 tables is 1000.
I have prepared the first four tables.
For the fifth table, I have trouble select obs (1000 minus sum(table 1 to 4)).

I can manually sum odsnumber but it will impact the efficiency given this has to be done routinely.
Can anyone guide me on how to improve these scripts?

```
Proc sql;
select nobs
into: odsnumber trimmed
from sashelp.vtable
where libname='work' and memname in ('table1' 'table2' 'table3' 'table4')
;quit;

data table5;
set source;
if 1<=_N_<=sum(1000,manual calculation of nobs from 4 tables);
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute the SUM of the four NOBS in the SQL and you wont have to manually calculate it.

In SQL I prefer to use `DICTIONARY` tables instead of `SASHELP.V*` views.  Use the views when needing to access metadata from a `DATA` or `PROC` step.

`libname` and `memname` values are ALWAYS uppercase when queried from the meta-data DICTIONARY tables.

Example:

```
data table1; do row = 1 to 10; output; end;
data table2; do row = 1 to 100; output; end;
data table3; do row = 1 to 100; output; end;
data table4; do row = 1 to 40 ; output; end;
data source; do row = 1 to 2500; output; end;

proc sql NOPRINT;
  select SUM(nobs) 
  into: NOBS_OF_4_TABLES trimmed
  from DICTIONARY.TABLES
  where libname='WORK' 
    and memname in ('TABLE1' 'TABLE2' 'TABLE3' 'TABLE4')
;

%put NOTE: &=NOBS_OF_4_TABLES;  %* Check log to see value computed;

data table5;
  set source;
  if _N_ > 1000 - &NOBS_OF_4_TABLES then stop;
run;
```